# Big-O analysis of a combination function

Tags: asymptotics

Prove that $$\binom{2n}{n} \in O\left(4^n/\sqrt{n}\right) $$
I am not familiar with markdown syntax so sorry for the formula display

Comment: You have that the binomial number is $\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$. Use the [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) with each of those factorials.

Comment: There's also a nice proof using an integral formula for ${2n \choose n}$ here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2948192/prove-central-binomial-coefficient-upper-bound

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you can find links to an argument using [Stirling's approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2979729/bounds-on-binom2nn) and an argument using an [integral formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2948192/prove-central-binomial-coefficient-upper-bound); here's a much more elementary argument (which gives a worse bound). Write $a_n = {2n \choose n}$. We have

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{(2n+2)! n!^2}{(2n)! (n+1)!^2} = \frac{4n+2}{n+1} = 4 - \frac{2}{n+1}$$

which gives

$$a_n = \prod_{i=1}^n \left( 4 - \frac{2}{i} \right) = 4^n \prod_{i=1}^n \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2i} \right) = 4^n \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2} \right) \left( 1 - \frac{1}{4} \right) \dots \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2n} \right).$$

Squaring $\frac{a_n}{4^n}$ gives

$$\begin{align*} \prod_{i=1}^n \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2i} \right)^2 & \le \prod_{i=1}^n \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2i-1} \right) \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2i} \right) \\
 &= \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2} \right) \left( 1 - \frac{1}{3} \right) \dots \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2n-1} \right) \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2n} \right) \\
 &= \frac{1}{2n} \end{align*}.$$

This gives

$$\boxed{ {2n \choose n} \le \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{2n}} }$$

although that constant $2$ in the denominator is not best possible. Doing this argument more carefully can get the best constant, which is $\pi$, using the Wallis product, as explained [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient#Asymptotic_growth).

Alternatively, the inequality $1 - x \le \exp(-x)$ gives

$$a_n \le 4^n \exp \left( \sum_{i=1}^n - \frac{1}{2i} \right) = 4^n \exp \left( - \frac{H_n}{2} \right)$$

where $H_n$ is the $n^{th}$ [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). The elementary inequality $H_n \ge \log n$ gives ${2n \choose n} \le \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ which is a bit worse, but this argument is very general. We could do a more careful analysis here by taking logarithms.

There's also a conceptual interpretation of the true asymptotic ${2n \choose n} \sim \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$ that comes from applying the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) to the binomial distribution $\text{Bin} \left( 2n, \frac{1}{2} \right)$. I think this is in some sense the best explanation of that funny $\sqrt{\pi n}$.